# How to set interval (time) of to execute javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I need to set interval in javascript.

I currently have javascript code whose execution is delayed, I need that code to be executed every x seconds. Is there any way to do that?

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 3000; //1 second

setTimeout(function() {
//MY CODE HERE
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Thank you

Comment: So use interval and not timeout???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use [`setInterval()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function:

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 3000; //1 second

setInterval(function() {
    // do stuff
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Comment: The codes i'm executing inside setInterval() makes div scroll, as it seems i cannot move the scroll up. how can it be possible to let scroll moves up or wherever in that code?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). It will execute the function every `x` milliseconds.

```
const delayInMilliseconds = 3000;
setInterval(() => {
    // Your code here
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```